# How do I ignore a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated. exception

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I know that my data is too large and that is why I am getting the exception. However, this seems more like a warning to me. Is there a property in the SQLCommand that I can set that would have this just be a warning and insert the truncated data anyhow? Trying to eliminate all possible questions that would be quickly answered. I cannot change the size of the column in the SQLDatabase. I do not have permission to do this. I would like to avoid going to each string and saying if length > x take substring. I just want this to be ignored at the command level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute `SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF` to suppress this message.  Or you can use `LEFT`||`RIGHT` functions to truncate data and pass the maximum number of character for the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn ANSI warnings to off and get around this, but this means either chaining commands to turn off and on or relying on Stored Procedures to handle this. I have not examined all database options, but I believe this can only be done on a batch level. Even if it can be done for the entire database, I don't think it can be set up table specific. And, even if can be done for the entire database, it is a bad idea. Best to only use the setting where you don't care about truncation.

In my opinion, truncate and ignore is a bad option, unless you really do not care about the data. And, if you don't care about it, why are you saving it anyway?